# Accessing element n+1 without exceeding matrix dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, sequence, indexoutofboundsexception

I have written a decent number of programs now where I've had to compare elements in sequential columns or rows. Unfortunately, the easiest way to do this - comparing element n with element n+1 (e.g. if matrix(n) > matrix(n+1)) has the inherent weakness of causing program errors once you get to the final element in the array and, thus, are referencing elements beyond the matrix dimensions. Are there efficient ways to do comparisons like this without running into this specific issue?

Importantly, data cannot be ignored so the final element in these examples needs to be accessed, but it will obviously not be compared to anything beyond it.

A concrete theoretical example is this: I have 100 columns with a timestamp. I am going cell by cell and figuring out if the stamps are within a specific range (e.g. within a 250ms block range) so I can sort them into blocks. So if cell one is within 0-250 it goes it block 1, if it is within 250-500 it goes in block 2, etc. One of my issues that multiple cells can be in the same block (e.g. cell 1 can be in block 1 but so can cell 2 and cell 3 would be in block 2) so as part of figuring out which cell goes where, I have a counter for block (m) and, after putting the current cell (n) in the appropriate block, I check the timestamp of cell n+1 and, if it is greater than m+1, I increase the block counter by 1.

Obviously I'm referencing sequentially and will run into the problem specified above. When I get to the final cell, no comparisons of n+1 will need to be made so I'll just shove it into it's appropriate block. But the way I have it set up right now I'm using a for loop to access all array elements 1:n. It just seems like there should be a better way to do this. Or is is simply just a matter of an additional 'if statement' for the last array element?

EDIT: So here's an example of what I currently have. It's taken from a larger program so I'll try to clarify best as I can.

```
binsize = 250;  %In ms
triallength = 16 * 1000; %In ms; 16 = trial time in seconds
timepoints = [0:binsize:triallength];
bincounter = 1; 
numtrials = 27;
for h = 1:numtrials
        for k = 1:length(input) %e.g. input here is 100x1
            if input(k,1) >= timepoints(1,bincounter) && input(k,1) < timepoints(1,bincounter) + binsize
                 outputmatrix(h, bincounter) = fixtimeleft; %Where variable 'fixtimeleft' was calculated elsewhere and variable 'outputmatrix' is of size numtrialsXtimepoints
                 if input(k+1,1) > timepoints(1,bincounter) && input(k+1,1) < timepoints(1,bincounter) + binsize %This is the offending line
                    ;
                else
                    bincounter = bincounter+1;
                end
           end
       end
end
```

Sorry for the messiness but this is extracted from a larger program where other processing is occurring that is irrelevant to the question - I just tried to keep in stuff that was pertinent but realize that can make this potentially difficult to understand so I can provide any clarification if necessary.

Comment: Within your loop, add a condition like `if n+1 > size(MATRIX, 2); break; end`. This way, your code will exit the for loop if `n+1` exceeds the number of columns in the matrix...

Comment: Could you a minimal example to clarify? I'm not quite sure if I fully understand your code.

Comment: Yeah I can add an example, no problem. I might have to annotate it because I'll extract it from the larger script; one sec.

Comment: Why don't you just use `for k = 1:length(input)-1`, or surround your inner-most `if` with another: `if k+1 < length(input)`. It's also worth noting that `input` is a **bad** variable name in Matlab, since it is an in built function...